# Simple iframe Facebook like button dissapeared

Tags: wordpress, post, iframe, facebook-like

I have just migrated a heavy wordpress blog to a new server.

A very basic post functionality has disappeared:

A simple FB like button that was using an iframe to display fb likes within a post page.

One can see the code upon browser inspection, but the front-end displays a blank div.

Given that the website has more than 10K posts and it is of crucial importance to keep the archive of likes, do you know how i can bring this back?

Here is an example of an iframe code:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bibliotheque.gr%2Farticle%2F81332&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:60px"></iframe>
```

and here is a screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEf5h.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to use https, and check the devtools:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.bibliotheque.gr/article/81765'
> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame
> 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bibliotheque.gr%2Farticle%2F81765&layout=standard&show_faces=false&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light'.
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.